# How to use variable inside querySelectorAll to select direct child

Tags: javascript, html-lists, parent-child, queryselector

How can i use variable with `document.querySelectorAll` to select all the direct `<li>` child elements. I would like to select the direct `<li>` tag of `main-navigation > ul` element and give a red border. I know that it can fix using `let firstLevelLi = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation > ul > li");`. But i am looking for a solution with variable as follows.

```
let parent = document.querySelector(".main-navigation > ul");
let li = document.querySelectorAll("`${parent}` > ul > li");
```

I need this to use along with a OOP function. I don't mention my OOP code here as it may be confuse everyone. Thats why i reduced it like this to address the core issue. My code is as follows. Hopes anyone can help me. Thanks in Advance!

```js
let parent = document.querySelector(".main-navigation > ul");
    let li = document.querySelectorAll("`${parent}` > ul > li");
    
    li.forEach((el)=>{
    el.style.border="2px solid red";
    });
```

```css
ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;font-family:arial;}
ul ul {padding-left:1rem;}
li {padding:.35rem;}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `let li = parent.querySelectorAll("ul > li");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tagname of `parent` inside the `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.main-navigation')

let li = document.querySelectorAll(`${parent.tagName} > ul > li`)

li.forEach(el => {
  el.style.border = '2px solid red'
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

ul ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li {
  padding: 0.35rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Aerial, your solution sounds good. Let me also know how can i select only the firstlevel `<li>` tag. That means, i don't want to select "About" tag child `<li>` tags. Hopes you understand it. Thank You for your initiation.

Comment: @RenJitsm check the edited answer

Comment: Hi Aerial, Wow....wonderfull. This is exactly what i was looking for. Let me know is there any documentation regarding "variable.tagName" to just refer it. Its a Wonderfull help and Solution. Its really saved lot of my time!!!. Many many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "parent" instead of "document" in:

```
let li = parent.querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll('li');
```

In your case, you need to separate the operation into two queries instead of one since each of the list elements in your example code is in some way a part of a ul element, so the `ul > li` will actually select all of them.

```
let li = parent.querySelectorAll("ul > li"); // this will not work as you want
```

If you expect that there will be multiple child ul, you can select all of them, then loop on and select their list elements.

```
  let li = [];
  parent.querySelectorAll("ul").forEach(ul => {
    li = [...li, ...ul.querySelectorAll('li')];
  });
```

Here is the full code:

```js
let parent = document.querySelector(".main-navigation > ul");
let li = parent.querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll('li');
    
    li.forEach((el)=>{
    el.style.border="2px solid red";
    });
```

```css
ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;font-family:arial;}
ul ul {padding-left:1rem;}
li {padding:.35rem;}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alaa, you are almost near of the another best solution. Now you selected `<li>` tag inside "About" menu. Actually I need border only for first level `<li>` tag. So that the border not required for `<li>` tag inside "About" tag. Hopes you understand. Thank You for your assistance!